# Quisiera saber como ingreso el resultado de una consulta postgreSQL en otra consulta totalmente distinta desde un script PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, poo

```
<?php  

require_once("conexion.php");
$dbconect=new conexion();
$dbconect->conectar();

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$fecha_nac = $_POST['fecha_nac'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
$cod_tlf = $_POST['cod_tlf'];
$numero_tlf = $_POST['numero_tlf'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cargo = $_POST['cargo'];
$departamentos = $_POST['departamentos'];
$horario = $_POST['horario'];

class personas
{
    function ingresar($nombre,$apellido,$cedula,$user,$pass,$fecha_nac,$direccion,$sexo,$cod_tlf,$numero_tlf,$email,$cargo,$departamentos,$horario)
    {   

        $firstquery="INSERT INTO personas(nombre, apellido, cedula, fecha_nac, direccion, email, id_sexo, id_cod_tlf, numero_tlf)
        VALUES ('".$nombre."','".$apellido."','".$cedula."','".$fecha_nac."','".$direccion."','".$email."',
                '".$sexo."','".$cod_tlf."','".$numero_tlf."')";
        $resultadofirst=pg_query($firstquery);

        $consulta=pg_query("SELECT MAX(id_persona) FROM personas");

        $secondquery="INSERT INTO empleados_locatel(id_departamento,id_horario,id_persona,cargo)
        VALUES ('".$departamentos."','".$horario."',$consulta,'".$cargo."')";
        $resultadosecond=pg_query($secondquery);

        $thirdquery="INSERT INTO usuarios(id_persona, nombre_user, pass_user)
        VALUES ($consulta,'".$user."','".$pass."')";
        $resultadothird=pg_query($thirdquery);
    }
}
$empleado =new personas();
$empleado->ingresar($nombre,$apellido,$cedula,$user,$pass,$fecha_nac,$direccion,$sexo,$cod_tlf,$numero_tlf,$email,$cargo,$departamentos,$horario);
?>
```

Y este es el error que me muestra. Por favor quien pueda ayudarme sera bienvenido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para futuras preguntas ten en cuenta que el texto mismo del mensaje de error habría sido mucho más útil que la imagen en este caso. Dicho mensaje indica un error de sintaxis en las líneas `75` y `79` de `login.php`. Puedes imprimir las dos consultas de esas líneas para revisar cómo se están construyendo. Una variable que usas y que no se sabe de dónde la sacas es esta: `$consulta`. No quiere decir que ella sea el motivo del error necesariamente. Conviene que depures tus consultas y los valores de tus variables. Para un futuro considera aplicar  consultas preparadas.